# EJB embedded container - dependency injection don't work?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, ioc-container

Have a look at following code:

```
@Local
public interface MyService {

    void printMessage();
}

@Stateless
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Override
    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("Hello from MyService.");
    }
}

@Stateless
@Named
public class Application {

    @EJB
    public MyService sampleService;

    private static Application getApplication() throws NamingException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(EJBContainer.APP_NAME, "admin");
        EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties); //.getContext();
        Context context = new InitialContext();

        Application application = (Application) context.lookup("java:global/admin/classes/Application");
        return application;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        Application application = getApplication();
        application.start(args);
    }

    private void start(String[] args) {
        sampleService.printMessage();
    }
}
```

I expected to have simpletService instance available at start() operation, but it is equal to null. All classes are part of one project (placed in separated files). Where I have made mistake? Thanks for advice.

Comment: That looks like it should work.  What application server are you using?  FYI, you should use EJBContainer.getContext() rather than new InitialContext()

Comment: I am using Glassfish 3.1. In first version I had EJBContainer.getContext() but it hadn't work also.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course.  You're using No Interface View.  The lookup returns a proxy, which is necessarily a subclass for NIV.  Because the method was private, you're calling a method directly on the proxy, which does not have injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found solution. When I changed start() operation to be public and injection started work fine.